# How to write a latex large Christoffel symbol from Einstein's theory of relativity?

Tags: symbols

How to write a latex large Christoffel symbol from Einstein's theory of relativity?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome! What is your question? Did you try `$\Gamma^i_{jk}$`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. But can you kindly make it larger?

Comment: You *could* use `\mathlarger`, which requires the `\usepackage{relsize}` package, e.g. compare `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
$\Gamma^i_{jk}$ ${\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Gamma}}^i_{jk}$
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, please add your comment as an answer. And provide this fact, that to make the math symbols larger add `\mathlarger` many times to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you point to a source where this enlarged symbol is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\mathlarger` to make math larger. Font sizes come in steps so you may have to apply it multiple times (yes, the font sizes are quantized, but this does not make this quantum gravity;-). For example, you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\Christoffel}[2]{\ensuremath{{\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Gamma}}^{#1}\!\!\!_{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\Gamma^i_{jk}$ vs.\ ${\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Gamma}}^i_{jk}$ vs.\
$\Christoffel{i}{jk}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which of those, if any, is the most beautiful is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

There is also one extra possibility to use a specific package for tensors called [tensor](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf). 
By clicking on the link highlighted in red you can read the complete guide. Here I enter two code options using this package. I prefer the first code where the subscripts are close to the word `\Gamma`.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$\tensor*{\Gamma}{*^{i}_{jk}}\quad \text{ or } \quad \Gamma\indices{^i_{jk}}$
\end{document}
```